# Add filter without overriding previous filters

Tags: css

I have this filter on my icons

```
.uiicon {
    filter:invert(51%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(153deg) saturate(100%);
    -webkit-filter: invert(51%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(153deg) saturate(100%);
    -moz-filter: invert(51%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(153deg) saturate(100%);
    -o-filter: invert(51%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(153deg) saturate(100%);
    -ms-filter: invert(51%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(153deg) saturate(100%);
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

it performs nicely and does what it wants.

But when I add an extra filter to a class it totally overrides the previous filter instead of nicely cascading

```
.icon1 {
    background-image: url('uiicons/%20(1).png');
    -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(12px 12px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
 }
```

Is there a way around it except making a hybrid class? i really don't like the idea of code duplication...

**EDIT**

i'm interested in finding out if there's a native way to achieve this. i'm not interested in css preprocessors or javascript solutions. I know how to do those.

Comment: Do you mind using JS? What about CSS preprocessing?

Comment: I know how to do it with js, but i'd rather find out if there's a native way to achieve this. I've found that sometimes there's somewhere someone with some obscure knowledge that can provide the needed clue.

Comment: as i stated, i'm interesting in finding out if there's a native way.